# Display SP Online list data as report in Excel Web Access Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports, excel-web-access-webpart

I have a SP Online list and I want to present this data as a report using Excel Web Access.

First is it possible to sync a SP Online list data to an excel file uploaded to SP document library as a report? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps below to add connection to a SP Online list and upload the excel file to a SP Online library. The data in the workbook will refresh automatically if the refresh control is enabled. After that, you can display the data using Excel Web Access web part.

1. Create a excel file in client.
2. Get external data from ODate Date Feed.
   [image]
3. Link to `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/<site>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc`.
4. Select the lists which you want to display and click Next.
5. Enter the information such as file name for this data connection and click Finish.
6. View this data as a table in the workbook.
7. Edit this data connection properties, set the refresh control to refresh data when opening the file or other refresh options as you want.

   [image]
8. Save the file and upload the file to a SP Online library.
9. Display the data using Excel Web Access web part.

Comment: Many thanks for the steps. It worked as expected. But people/group column values and lookup column values got exported as IDs in excel,is there a way that I can export their value instead of IDs?